# Query for replacing the value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have  table and have a data as follows

```
    Ac1        ac2       name   ind
    123        223       john     y
    123        000       john     y
    123        001       john     N
    123        002       roy      N
    223        000       roy      N
    223        001       roy      Y
    223        002       james    y
    234        001       james    y
    234        000       james    y
```

I have this table I want to show ac2 is other than 000 any other value i need to show the ind1 new column as the ind of 000 value

```
    Ac1        ac2       name   ind     ind1
    123        223       john     y      Y
    123        000       john     y      Y
    123        001       john     N      Y
    123        002       roy      N      N
    223        000       roy      N      N
    223        001       roy      Y      N
    223        002       james    y      Y
    234        001       james    y      Y
    234        000       james    y      Y
```

My table always has account with 000 and now if i want to view it by name then I am not getting expected result

```
         select ac1, ac2, ind,case when ac2 = 0 then ind end as ind1 from   table;
```

Comment: I don't follow your question at all.  Are you trying to select rows?  Are you trying to define `ind1`?

Comment: I am trying to get one extra column  name ind1 which gets the values in ind when the ac2 is 000 and if ac2 is 001,002,033 .. I only consider 000 value ind in ind1

Comment: @gordon well my issue is when i am give a parameter as name and try to select the output :p_name and if name = roy and i need to select the value of 123 000 ind coz roy has no 000 account if select by name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.ac1, a.ac2, a.name, a.ind, b.ind ind1 
from table a join (select distinct name, ind from table where ac2='000')b on a.name=b.name
```

Comment: I dont want to display null i want the ind value of ac2='000' to be displayed for others also

Comment: Ok I think i get what you need now - ok have a look at updated code